# "Мерзавец" — откуда взялось ругательство

Tags: этимология

"Мерзавец", как я понимаю, произошло от слова "мерзнуть", так? Но почему это стало ругательством, да еще и довольно крепким?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее не от "мёрзнуть", а от "мерзить":
http://old_russian.academic.ru/5010/%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%80%D0%B7%D1%A3%D1%82%D0%B8
МЬР|ЗѢТИ , ЖОУ, ЗИТЬ глагол со знач."вызывать отвращение":
 ѥдинъ волкъ всю чреду смутить. одинъ тать на всѣ стороны мерзить. МПр XIV, 63 об.;и зѣло ми мерзитъ животъ ихъ стара блѧдива, || б҃гата лжива, ѹбога хѹпава. Пч к. XIV, 137–137 об.; люби||ма в малѣ и зѣло мерзѧща. ЖВИ XIV–XV, 53б–в; мьрзѧхѹть имъ смѣрениѥ. и поч(с)тиша возвышениѥ.Пал 1406, 51а.

От "мерзить" образовалось утраченное прилаг. мерзавый - мерзый - мерзкий - вызывающий отвращение, от них - мерзавец.

Значение слова "мерзить", конечно, восходит к праславянскому корню *morzъ глагола "мёрзнуть"(от него  прилаг. мёрзлый)- испытывать холод, дрожь от мороза и дрожь от неприятных ощущений похожи.

Кстати, отсюда ещё омоним-мерзавец, мерзавчик - "самая маленькая мера, допустимая при продаже водки (раньше = 1/200 ведра)", название объясняется сильным действием. От ме́рзкий. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — Фасмер 1964—1973.

Answer (score 3):

Этимология «мерзавца» восходит к слову «мерзлый». Холод даже для северных народов никаких приятных ассоциаций не вызывал, поэтому «мерзавцем» стали называть холодного, бесчувственного, равнодушного, черствого, бесчеловечного... в общем крайне неприятного субъекта. Слово «мразь», кстати, родом оттуда же. Как и популярные ныне «отморозки».

Answer (score 0):

В начале 80-х гг. на страницах журнала "Русская речь" встречал такую версию появления пары слов, связанных с одной из форм расправы с преступниками на морозе: замерзающий - мерзавец, а поливающий его водой - подлец. Тогда, помню, с ней согласился, хотя поливать и подливать  - совсем не одно и тоже, да и последнему подлецу по нашему пониманию, далеко до палача.

Думаю, эти слова могли означать злодея в одном лице - и замерзающего, и уже замёрзшего, покрывшегося льдом.